# How to keep scroll bar bottom if div is continuously update

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var b = document.getElementById('chat');
b.scrollTop = b.scrollHeight;
```

is not working if div content is update please give me another way to keep scroll bar bottom of div also update message in div.

Comment: just use a big int like 3286325762 instead of the value

Comment: If the div is continuously updated and you want to keep the scroll bar at the bottom why bother with a scroll bar? The client won't be able to use it to scroll up since the div is  continuously being updated and forced to scroll to the bottom or could become very annoying if the client scrolls up and the div is then updated and being forced to scroll down.

Comment: you can use an `MutationObserver` (design pattern) to observe the element's height and then set the scroll to for example the `innerHeight` of the `document` or scroll by the difference between the new div's height and the old.

Comment: check this link for more info about `MutationObserver` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Keep in mind that autoscrolling UX can be very annoying for some users. For example say you're trying to scroll up in chat but if the person chatting with you keeps sending messages it jumps you back to the most recent part of the conversation. Implement a threshold to check if the scrollbar was previously at about the height of the new content added before autoscrolling to avoid annoying issues like that.